# Calling complicated stored procedures from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm looking for the most elegant way of making Entity Framework call my stored procedures (delete, insert & update). The catch is that I use database-first,  I can't change the stored procedures and there are more arguments to the stored procedures than there are columns in the related table. Id rather not use functional imports since they have to be called by my code, and not by the framework. It doesn't feel elegant enough.

There is a nice solution for Linq to SQL. The code generator gives me Insert( instance)  (and Delete, Update) partial methods that are called by the framework if I implement them in a partial class. From that method I just have to call this.() with the instance variables and then add my extra arguments.

What is the easiest and most elegant way of doing this in Entity Framework?

/BE

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you can't - if you can't change the stored procedures, then `ExecuteFunction` or a function import is your only option.  I would dearly love to be proved wrong though.

Have you considered creating new stored procedures in the form EF wants, and calling the existing SPs from them?

Comment: How would I get EF to call the new SPs without having to do it directly with function imports? Feels weird that Linq to SQL can handle this common problem easily, but EF that is the "future" can't.